# how to simulate gpg severkey DoS attack?

Tags: pgp, gnupg

I tried to simulate this attack in my PC but I could not generate a poison key, I used Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) and GPG software (gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.4). I tried to manipulate public key and import it to pubkeyring as a poisoned key but unfortunately failed.

```
test@GnuPG:~/Documents/gpg$ gpg --import manipulated_PK.asc

gpg: CRC error; 246C33 - A03158

gpg: read_block: read error: Invalid keyring

gpg: import from 'manipulated_PK.asc' failed: Invalid keyring

gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

I need your help how to generate a large size posioned key https://tech.michaelaltfield.net/2019/07/14/mitigating-poisoned-pgp-certificates/

Comment: Please only have one question per post.